# Timestamp at which phone turned off?

Tags: android, android-alarms

For Android devices, is there any way to find out at what time ( or timestamp ) the device turned off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont think there's any predefined support for that. However, its easy to get this done with your custom logic. All, you need to do is to define a `BroadcastReceiver` which listens for intent `android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN`. Once it receives the intent, simply save the current `Date` in *SharedPreferences*, *SQLite* or where ever you want. Later, the phone is booted, read the saved value to know the estimated time when the phone was shutdown. For example:

receiver code:

```
public class ShutdownReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //save the date here
    }
}
```

and in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name=".ShutdownReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```